# MQTT slow to subscribe and debounce problems

Tags: arduino, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm after some desperately needed help please.

My setup consists of two arduinos (EtherTens) and a Raspberry Pi (running Mosquitto MQTT broker and Home Assistant). On one Arduino I have a security sensor shield with two PIRs attached and publishing states to the broker (this works 100% how it should).

On my other arduino, I have a couple of relay 8 driver shields (they use I2C) connected to two 8 channel relay boards (total of 16 relays connected).

I have toggle switches connected to switch a few lights in the house for hardware activation plus I have it setup to be activated through Home Assistant with MQTT topics.

The issues I've come across is random relay activation from turning other lights on in the house. I think there's some line interference somewhere and am hoping that a software debounce might solve the issue but I am lost in the code (I already have 10k pulldown resistors on my toggle switch setup).
The other issue is the the Arduino running the relay shields is really (and I mean really) slow to subscribe to the broker...I'm talking anywhere up to 10 seconds at times.

Would anyone be able to suggest the best way to fix my code please?

```
// This subscribes to MQTT IOT get the PIR sensor states //

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define SHIELD_1_I2C_ADDRESS  0x20  // 0x20 is the address with all jumpers removed
#define SHIELD_2_I2C_ADDRESS  0x21  // 0x21 is the address with a jumper on position A0
#define MAC_I2C_ADDRESS       0x50  // Microchip 24AA125E48 I2C ROM address

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[]    = {  0xDE, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 2, 110);
IPAddress server(192, 168, 2, 149);

byte shield1BankA = 0; // Current status of all outputs on first shield, one bit per output
byte shield2BankA = 0; // Current status of all outputs on second shield, one bit per output

const int buttonPin2 = 2;
const int buttonPin3 = 3;
const int buttonPin4 = 4;
const int buttonPin5 = 5;
const int buttonPin6 = 6;

int buttonState2;
int buttonState3;
int buttonState4;
int buttonState5;
int buttonState6;

int lastButtonState2 = LOW;
int lastButtonState3 = LOW;
int lastButtonState4 = LOW;
int lastButtonState5 = LOW;
int lastButtonState6 = LOW;

unsigned long lastDebounceTime2 = 0;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime3 = 0;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime4 = 0;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime5 = 0;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime6 = 0;

unsigned long debounceDelay2 = 50;
unsigned long debounceDelay3 = 50;
unsigned long debounceDelay4 = 50;
unsigned long debounceDelay5 = 50;
unsigned long debounceDelay6 = 50;

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, ethClient);

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // handle message arrived
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the Hallway Light
  if (strcmp(topic, "left/hallwaylight") == 0) {
    if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
      setLatchChannelOn(1);
      client.publish("left/hallwaylight/state", "1");
      delay(500);
    }
     else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
    {
      setLatchChannelOff(1);
      delay(500);
      client.publish("left/hallwaylight/state", "0");
    }
}

// Switch on the Workshop Light - Sensor 2
if (strcmp(topic, "left/workshoplight") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(2);
    client.publish("left/workshoplight/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(2);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/workshoplight/state", "0");
  }
}
/*
// Switch on the #############
if (strcmp(topic, "left/sensor2") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(2);
    client.publish("left/workshoplight/state", "1");
    Serial.println("Workshop Light On");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(2);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/workshoplight/*&^*&^&*", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the ####################
if (strcmp(topic, "left/sensor2") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(2);
    client.publish("left/workshoplight/state", "1");
    Serial.println("Workshop Light On");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(2);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/workshoplight/khebfjseghf", "0");
  }
} */
// Switch on the Fountain
if (strcmp(topic, "left/fountain") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(8);
    client.publish("left/fountain/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(8);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/fountain/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Entrance Lights
if (strcmp(topic, "left/entrancelights") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(7);
    client.publish("left/entrancelights/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(7);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/entrancelights/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Foyer Lights
if (strcmp(topic, "left/foyerlights") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(6);
    client.publish("left/foyerlights/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(6);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/foyerlights/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Driveway Lights - Sensor 1
if (strcmp(topic, "left/drivewaylights") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(9);
    client.publish("left/drivewaylights/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(9);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/drivewaylights/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Spa Light
if (strcmp(topic, "left/spalight") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(10);
    client.publish("left/spalight/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(10);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/spalight/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Pool Light
if (strcmp(topic, "left/poollight") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(11);
    client.publish("left/poollight/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(11);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/poollight/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Tree Light
if (strcmp(topic, "left/treelight") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(12);
    client.publish("left/treelight/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(12);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/treelight/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Fountains
if (strcmp(topic, "left/fountains") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(13);
    client.publish("left/fountains/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(13);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/fountains/state", "0");
  }
}

// Switch on the Spa
if (strcmp(topic, "left/spa") == 0) {
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
  {
    setLatchChannelOn(16);
    client.publish("left/spa/state", "1");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((char)payload[0] == '0') //Controlled from Home Assistant
  {
    setLatchChannelOff(16);
    delay(500);
    client.publish("left/spa/state", "0");
  }
 }
}

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(); // Wake up I2C bus
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  // Note - the default maximum packet size is 128 bytes. If the
  // combined length of clientId, username and password exceed this,
  // you will need to increase the value of MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE in
  // PubSubClient.h

  /* Set up the Relay8 shields */
  initialiseShield(SHIELD_1_I2C_ADDRESS);
  sendRawValueToLatch1(0);  // If we don't do this, channel 6 turns on! I don't know why

  initialiseShield(SHIELD_2_I2C_ADDRESS);
  sendRawValueToLatch2(0);  // If we don't do this, channel 6 turns on! I don't know why

pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin4, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin5, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin6, INPUT);

}

void loop()
{
if (!client.connected()) {
  reconnect();
}

int reading2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
int reading3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
int reading4 = digitalRead(buttonPin4);
int reading5 = digitalRead(buttonPin5);
int reading6 = digitalRead(buttonPin6);

if (reading2 != lastButtonState2) {
  lastDebounceTime2 = millis();
  }
if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime2) > debounceDelay2) {
  if (reading2 != buttonState2) {
    buttonState2 = reading2;

  if ((buttonPin2 == HIGH) && What to put here????) {
    toggleLatchChannel(1);
    client.publish("left/hallwaylight/state", "1");
  }
  /*if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) //Digital pin for Hall Light
  {
    toggleLatchChannel(1);
    delay(1000);
  }*/
 }
}

lastButtonState2 = reading2;

if (digitalRead(3) == HIGH) //Digital pin for Fountain
{
  toggleLatchChannel(6);
  delay(1000);
}

if (digitalRead(4) == HIGH) //Digital pin for Entrance Lights
{
  toggleLatchChannel(7);
  delay(1000);
}

if (digitalRead(5) == HIGH) //Digital pin for Foyer Lights
{
  toggleLatchChannel(8);
  delay(1000);
}

if (digitalRead(6) == HIGH) //Digital pin for Driveway Lights - to be removed
{
  toggleLatchChannel(9);
  delay(1000);
}

client.loop();
}

void reconnect() {
// Loop until we're reconnected
while (!client.connected()) {
  Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
  // Attempt to connect
  if (client.connect("leftArduinoClient")) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.subscribe("left/#");
  } else {
    Serial.print("failed, rc=");
    Serial.print(client.state());
    Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
    // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
    delay(5000);
   }
 }
}

void initialiseShield(int shieldAddress)
{
// Set addressing style
Wire.beginTransmission(shieldAddress);
Wire.write(0x12);
Wire.write(0x20); // use table 1.4 addressing
Wire.endTransmission();

// Set I/O bank A to outputs
Wire.beginTransmission(shieldAddress);
Wire.write(0x00); // IODIRA register
Wire.write(0x00); // Set all of bank A to outputs
Wire.endTransmission();
}

void toggleLatchChannel(byte channelId)
{
if ( channelId >= 1 && channelId <= 8 )
{
  byte shieldOutput = channelId;
  byte channelMask = 1 << (shieldOutput - 1);
  shield1BankA = shield1BankA ^ channelMask;
  sendRawValueToLatch1(shield1BankA);
}
else if ( channelId >= 9 && channelId <= 16 )
{
  byte shieldOutput = channelId - 8;
  byte channelMask = 1 << (shieldOutput - 1);
  shield2BankA = shield2BankA ^ channelMask;
  sendRawValueToLatch2(shield2BankA);
  }
}

void setLatchChannelOn (byte channelId)
{
if ( channelId >= 1 && channelId <= 8 )
{
  byte shieldOutput = channelId;
  byte channelMask = 1 << (shieldOutput - 1);
  shield1BankA = shield1BankA | channelMask;
  sendRawValueToLatch1(shield1BankA);
}
else if ( channelId >= 9 && channelId <= 16 )
{
  byte shieldOutput = channelId - 8;
  byte channelMask = 1 << (shieldOutput - 1);
  shield2BankA = shield2BankA | channelMask;
  sendRawValueToLatch2(shield2BankA);
  }
}

void setLatchChannelOff (byte channelId)
{
if ( channelId >= 1 && channelId <= 8 )
{
  byte shieldOutput = channelId;
  byte channelMask = 255 - ( 1 << (shieldOutput - 1));
  shield1BankA = shield1BankA & channelMask;
  sendRawValueToLatch1(shield1BankA);
}
else if ( channelId >= 9 && channelId <= 16 )
{
  byte shieldOutput = channelId - 8;
  byte channelMask = 255 - ( 1 << (shieldOutput - 1));
  shield2BankA = shield2BankA & channelMask;
  sendRawValueToLatch2(shield2BankA);
  }
}

void sendRawValueToLatch1(byte rawValue)
{
Wire.beginTransmission(SHIELD_1_I2C_ADDRESS);
Wire.write(0x12);        // Select GPIOA
Wire.write(rawValue);    // Send value to bank A
shield1BankA = rawValue;
Wire.endTransmission();
}

void sendRawValueToLatch2(byte rawValue)
{
Wire.beginTransmission(SHIELD_2_I2C_ADDRESS);
Wire.write(0x12);        // Select GPIOA
Wire.write(rawValue);    // Send value to bank A
shield2BankA = rawValue;
Wire.endTransmission();
}

/** Required to read the MAC address ROM */
byte readRegister(byte r)
{
unsigned char v;
Wire.beginTransmission(MAC_I2C_ADDRESS);
Wire.write(r);  // Register to read
Wire.endTransmission();

Wire.requestFrom(MAC_I2C_ADDRESS, 1); // Read a byte
while (!Wire.available())
{
  // Wait
}
v = Wire.read();
return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to the broker may take long because of the delay in this function:

```
void reconnect() {
// Loop until we're reconnected
while (!client.connected()) {
  Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
  // Attempt to connect
  if (client.connect("leftArduinoClient")) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.subscribe("left/#");
  } else {
    Serial.print("failed, rc=");
    Serial.print(client.state());
    Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
    // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
    delay(5000);
   }
 }
}
```

If you fail to connect on the first attempt, the program will wait for 5 seconds. Have you checked with serial monitor if this is the case? You should see two "failed..." messages.

As for relays: debouncing is only for hardware switches - when you press a button there is a short period when electrcal contacts in it bounce back and forth connecting and disconnecting several times. When you connect a switch to a microcontroller, it will read several transitions of digital pin connected to a button. Debouncing is a way to ignore these short pulses.

That being said, there is no need to debounce a signal that comes from another microcontroller, or a PC - there are no mechanical parts that can oscillate generating "fake" pulses. Try to write a short test program that will just activate all relays in a sequence, one at a time, without reading any external inputs. That way you will know, if the problem comes from a bug in your code, or is it a hardware problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I run this through the serial monitor every time as part of my own debugging process. The client never fails to connect to the broker (which is a good thing) therefore I don't think the delay will come into play at all.

Comment: Regarding the debouncing etc, the same thing happens when I use a sketch that just switches in sequence. There must be some sort of interference coming from the standard light switches that transfers to the Arduino and randomly switches on the relays. Maybe a dirty earth.

Comment: @KeiranWyllie is 10s time measured from "Attempting MQTT connection...", or from start of the system? Regarding relays, post a link to a shield that you are using.

Comment: the 10s is from the last batch of subscriptions process to the next if that makes sense.

Comment: This is the EtherTen - [link](http://www.freetronics.com.au/products/etherten) and this is the relay shield - [link] (http://www.freetronics.com.au/collections/shields/products/relay8-8-channel-relay-driver-shield#.WA6etpN95E4)

Comment: I'm looking to test a theory and connect the toggle switches directly to my Raspberry Pi GPIO pins to be controlled via Home Assistant.

Comment: @KeiranWyllie How do you power the relay shield?

Comment: I've removed the jumper on the JD-VCC pin and connect that to a 5V power source with the GND pin connected to same source. The VCC pin next to the IN pins is connected to 5V on the EtherTen.

Comment: So you have same 5V power supply for Arduino and relay board? And you have 5V relays?

Comment: No sorry, I wasn't clear on that. They 5V supplies are from different sources. One is from an old computer power supply and the other comes from a POE switch.

Comment: Ok, and your relays are for 5VDC?

Comment: 5V DC input to switch 240V AC

Comment: Looks like I've narrowed down the delay issue a little. It seems that if I disconnect the EtherTen running the security sensor shield, then any switching done through Home Assistant (via MQTT broker) occurs straight away. Once I connect the EtherTen back up to my network, I get delays again.